# Sort By in Left Bar Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to show Sort by instead of a selectbox to clickable text Newest, Highest Price, Lowest Price in on left toolbar in Category page, if there any way we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

edit toolbar template

app/design/frontend/**[theme]**/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

```
<div class="sort-by">
    <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
            <?php if($_key=='price'):?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>">
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) . ' ' . $this->__('asc') ?>
            </a>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'desc') ?>">
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) . ' ' . $this->__('desc') ?>
            </a>
        <?php else:?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'desc') ?>">
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```